# Add residency/nationality to Careers site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Where you have permission to work is obviously important. Where you're a citizen can also be important. You could do this with free text but that wouldn't necessarily be accurate to search so I would suggest:

- Citizenship: listing countries;
- Permanent residency: listing countries;
- Work Permits for the most relevant countries (US/Canada, EU, Japan, Singapore, Hong Kong, Australia).

Comment: I don't think that anything besides the list if countries you have the right in is relevant. At least in the EU, employers are not allowed to discriminate on the grounds of nationality as long as you have the right to work there (with a few notable exceptions such as the defence industry).

Comment: @DrJokepu: That's true, but the fields wouldn't be compulsory.  If you happen to know though that you are looking for work in a field where such things are relevant (such defense contracting), you could volunteer the information in your CV.

Comment: It's still useful. If a USA employer is looking at your CV and sees you are in the UK, you could list that you are a US citizen/or right to work in the USA.

Comment: I would guess that employers "read between the lines" somewhat when looking for candidates. e.g. I am Canadian and don't *currently* have the right to work in the US, but I am regularly contacted by US recruiters (presumably because it wouldn't be difficult to get such permits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every location will have a small checkbox;

> [ ] I have the legal right to work in this location

This will be deployed next week

Comment: You still the "nationality" field. Some companies would care about what is the nationality of the candidate before contacting (whether this is right or wrong).

For those in countries where the checkbox is not enabled (I see the text is misleading, but this is another issue) this is also important information.